# Spyder 5.0.0 comment and indentation buttons missing

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder, toolbar

I have recently updated to Spyder 5.0.0. I can't seem to find the "edit toolbar" which has the comment/uncomment and indentation buttons. Was this removed in the latest version or am I looking in the wrong place?

Normally, I would select View > Toolbars > Edit toolbar. How do I get these buttons back in version 5.0.0?

P.s. I am aware of the shortcuts, however, I prefer using the buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) Yes, unfortunately the Edit toolbar (that contained those buttons) was removed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That's a pity, I liked the edit toolbar.

Comment: I liked it too. Why was it removed. I think it is better to click a button instead of pressing some keyboard combinations.

Comment: Sorry, we didn't have an easy way to keep those buttons in the interface.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to comment/uncomment using keyboard shortcuts but if you want block indentation, you can select the lines and press Tab. You can use Shift+Tab for unindentation. It works on all text editors I've ever seen.

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl+1 keyboard shortcut comments/uncomments the selected lines.